# Git push local folder

Tags: git, git-svn

Понимаю, что тему наверное стоило назвать как-то по-другому, но суть вот в чем.
Есть bare репозиторий на сервере, откуда клонируются нескольким разработчикам репозитории на их локальные машины. На сервере так же есть и клиентский (не bare) репозиторий. Когда один из разработчиков делает коммит и пуш, соответствующий хук, который привязан к bare репозиторию (post-push hook), пушит данный репозиторий на локальный серверный. Это сделано для того, чтобы разработчики сразу видели на сервере, что и как они изменили и кто еще что изменял в ближайшее время визуально, т.е. прямо на сайте. Всё удобно, но есть одна проблема.

Положим сегодня весь день разработчик А работает над папкой Х, а разработчик В над У. В заходить в папку Х и менять там что-то не собирается, так же не собирается и разработчик А ничего менять в папке У. Тем не менее, даже не смотря на то, что они работают в совершенно разных директориях и над разными файлами, если не сделать перед КАЖДЫМ пушем пулл, то возникает конфликт. Что очевидно, ведь пушится не та папка, которую он менял, а весь репозиторий.

Хотелось бы найти такое решение, которое либо бы пушило на сервер только одну директорию, либо с помощью нескольких веток и их слияния добивалось нужного результата на сервере. Но слабо себе представляю, как корректно то или другое реализовать. Буду рад любой помощи.

А если у кого-то возникнут еще какие-то идеи, то тоже будет здорово.

Answer (score 4):

Разработчиков A и B спасут локальные бранчи, которые они могут пушить на удаленный сервер.

```
git checkout -b branchA
```

Пишем код, коммитим и т.п.

```
git push origin branchA:branchA
```

Теперь наш бранч на удаленном сервере и доступен другим разработчикам для пула.

```
git pull
git branch --track branchA
git checkout branchA
```

Теперь branchA локально у разработчика B. Можно пулить и смотреть.

Каждый работает в своих бранчах до завершения всей работы и до мерджа в master ни с кем не конфликтует.

Comment: а как же быть с тем, что нужно еще в локальный репозиторий на сервере это пуллить? эти бранчи нужно как-то сливать там (в локал-репозитории) при каждом пуше в bare репозиторий, чтобы изменения сразу были визуально видны на сайте.

Comment: После того как работа завершена, локальный бранч мерджится в мастер и пушится на сервер (т.е. в bare репу, если ничего не менялось). А там отработает ваш post-push hook. 

После этого, кстати, локальные и удаленные бранчи, созданные разработчиками, можно удалить.

Comment: это конечно все равно немножко не то, что я имел ввиду, но так или иначе большое спасибо за помощь и отзывы! 

проблему я решил через имитацию force pull-a при срабатывании хука post-update.